# Is there any way to measure code similarity in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I don't know much in this domain. But I guess if we can use `quote` to get the AST, can we use the AST to measure the similarity of code? Because if we want to do `Fine-Grained Reuse`, it will be great that we can have an analyzer that tell the similarity of code, I think.

Comment: There are lots of ways to detect code similarity (see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5748/are-there-tools-to-determine-code-similarity/85190) that wouldn't necessarily be restricted to Elixir.

Comment: thanks, I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively simple to compare AST tuples and determine if they are similar. I'm not sure how that helps with Code reuse though.

I've created a library for determining if Elixir data structures are similar for various definitions of similar.

https://github.com/philosophers-stone/phenetic

My definitions of similar tend to focus on the basic type of a term in the limited set of collection terms. i.e. A Map that has lists of Atoms as values. But I have used it with simple code examples.

```
test "congruent quote do output" do
  data = quote do: Enum.map(1..3, fn(x) -> x*x end)
  data_transform = quote do: Enum.map(1..3, fn(y) -> y*y end)
  congruent =  PhStPhenetic.congruent(data)
  assert true == congruent.(data_transform)
end
```

That was mostly to insure that it worked with a complicated nested structure rather than any specific application to code restructuring.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps with reusing code, either. I just think if two functions are similiar, can they combine to one?

Comment: I googled Fine-Grained Reuse and it appears to mostly focus on OO languages and suggesting refactors if you are implementing the same method in multiple objects. I'm not sure how directly that applies to Elixir.